# WordPress: Override parent theme class function in child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, parent-child

I want to override function in child theme, which is defined inside a class in parent theme.

Here is the sample code:

```
class A extends B{
   function __construct(){
      $this->add_ajax('sync_post_data', 'need_to_override');
   }
   //other functions
   function need_to_override(){
      //function code
   }

}
```

**Additional Information:**

Class B extends Class C and Class C is the root class where `add_ajax` is defined.

**What I've tried:**

1. As the function is not pluggable so I can't override function directly in child theme.
2. Secondly I tried to remove ajax action and add my custom action. It throws 500 internal server error.

   ```
   remove_action( 'wp_ajax_sync_post_data', 'need_to_override' );
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_sync_post_data', 'custom_function' );

   function custom_function(){
      //function code with my custom modification
   }
   ```

Any help please...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just override that method of class in just two simple steps.

**Here's how:**

1. Open child theme `functions.php`
2. Create new class like this:

   ```
   add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {


      class D extends A{

         function need_to_override(){
            //original function code with your custom modifications
         }

      }

      new D();
   });
   ```

PS: It will work but I'm not sure if it is the best way or not!

Comment: I am not sure how this should work. Eventually the function that will be invoked by parent theme is `A::need_to_override()` rather than the new `D::need_to_override()`, unless I understand something wrong.