# WordPress: Customize Ajax request response via filter

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, add-filter

There is a function in parent theme and I want to customize success message, I don't want to make change in parent theme file. And the function is not pluggable so I can't override it. After digging, I found that I can use `add_filter` hook to filter response.

I wrote this code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_ajax_sync-data', 'custom_sync_data' );

function custom_sync_data(){
   $response = array(
               'success' => true,
               'message' => 'Date is updated'
               );
   wp_send_json($response);
}
```

It does the job but it always returns `success` message, without any validation. I don't know, how to pass parameter for validation or decision making.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
function custom_sync_data($params){
    //$params can be data or parameters you will have to pass
    //or you will have to check
    //based on that your setup validation or logic
    $response = array(
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Date is updated'
    );
}
wp_send_json($response);
```

You may also use `var_dump($params)` to check if anything is passed to function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already tried that but there isn't any param, it prints nothing.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I think the question is very clear but lemme briefly explain again, there is a function which inserts data in database. After the insertion, it sends success message. And I want to customize that message without affecting parent theme. The code (I added in question) sends correct message but it always send that message, doesn't matter what happens inside function. It even works, if I put `exit();` in the beginning of parent theme function. So, I want to validate current response of function, if it is success then send my custom message instead of original message. Hopefully it make sense now..

Comment: Can you post code of the function in the parent them which want to override?

Comment: There is more than 1500 lines of code so can't show you. However you can check my other question to understand [code structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293310/wordpress-override-parent-theme-class-function-in-child-theme/53331819#53331819).